# OpenStack - Check for Availability of Container C# .NET

Tags: openstack, rackspace-cloud, rackspace

I have integrated openstack to my .net solution. I am using CloudFilesProvider to create and delete a container. Is there any provision to check for the existence of a container using C#.

I know it is possible to check by getting ObjectStore and find ContainerExists property. But i am not sure how to get this property filled.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have used the second option you have provided, check for createContainer and check by option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ObjectStore` is an enumeration that defines the possible values returned by calls like `IObjectStorageProvider.CreateContainer`. For example, you could get an `ObjectStore` by attempting to *create* the container you're checking, and the return value would be `ContainerExists` if the container already exists. Unfortunately you could always end up with `ContainerCreated` returned by that call, i.e. if you use `CreateContainer` to check for a container's existence, then even if the container didn't exist before "checking", it would afterwards.

While it's definitely not clean, one option is calling `GetContainerMetadata`. The call will throw an `ItemNotFoundException` if the container doesn't exist.

Comment: So you are saying as i have mentioned createContainer method is only available for checking the existence of a container.

Comment: No, I am saying it seems you should use `GetContainerMetadata` to check the existence. If the method throws an `ItemNotFoundException`, the container does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Are you, by chance, using this Container as a CDN?

When **deleting** a CDN, you must also call the method "DisableCDNOnContainer" against the Container. Also, if you call the method "ListCDNContainers", you must filter out **deleted** CDN Containers by checking the property "CDNEnabled".

This is because deleted Containers "hang around" until their ttl expires.